# Wal-E cron job not executing

Tags: cron, postgresql

I have a `cron` job setup that is suppose to be running the wal-e backup-push command. The command works fine if manually ran through the command line. As the `postgres` user of course. So I setup a cron job to run this under the `postgres` user. It runs but does not do anything. The cron log says the job was completed.

Am I missing something obvious here? Any suggestions or help would be great.

```
0 2 * * * source ~/.bashrc && envdir /etc/wal-e.d/env wal-e backup-push /db01/pg
```

I've also tried.

```
0 2 * * * bash -l -c 'source ~/.bashrc && envdir /etc/wal-e.d/env wal-e backup-push /db01/pg'
```

Cron Log Messages:

`CROND[31371]: (postgres) CMD (bash -l -c 'source ~/.bashrc && envdir /etc/wal-e.d/env wal-e backup-push /db01/pg')`

`CROND[31655]: (postgres) CMD (/usr/bin/envdir /etc/wal-e.d/env /usr/local/bin/wal-e backup-push /db01/pg)`

Comment: Please post a sample of the log, sometimes this helps determine how the command ran - e.g. I ran in to a similar issue the other day and perusing the logs showed that the command that was run was shorter than the one in cron and I had to escape a special character to fix it (http://www.ducea.com/2008/11/12/using-the-character-in-crontab-entries/ - not my blog, just for reference). You don't seem to have a % symbol in your command, however it'd still be useful to see.

Comment: Here is the output from the log.

CROND[31371]: (postgres) CMD (bash -l -c 'source ~/.bashrc && envdir /etc/wal-e.d/env wal-e backup-push /db01/pg')

Comment: Also tried this with no luck. 

CROND[31655]: (postgres) CMD (/usr/bin/envdir /etc/wal-e.d/env /usr/local/bin/wal-e backup-push /db01/pg)

Answer (score 0):

This command is the final solution. It turned out that I was using the incorrect envdir path. I found the correct path by using which envdir when logged into the shell.

`source ~/.bashrc; /usr/local/bin/envdir /etc/wal-e.d/env wal-e backup-push /db01/pg`

Answer (score -1):

Not working. Tried following option in cron.

/usr/local/bin/envdir /etc/wal-e.d/env /usr/local/bin/wal-e backup-push /pg/data

bash -c "/usr/local/bin/envdir /etc/wal-e.d/env /usr/local/bin/wal-e backup-push /pg/data"

source ~/.bashrc && envdir; /usr/local/bin/envdir /etc/wal-e.d/env /usr/local/bin/wal-e backup-push /pg/data

Comment: This isn't an answer to the original question. If you've got a similar but different problem then best to ask a new question with more details.